# Create Routes from tasks

Tags: forms, learning, geolocation, education, administration

In the admin panel, I have the ability to create a game using a multi-step form. There is one game type that gives the user the ability to place tasks on the map and create a routes from these points. Now the flow looks like: create tasks >next> Create Routes from tasks. The user can click on the map and make a marker and add a task to this marker, or he can click on the button on particular tasks to add the location to this task, the route will be created in order to add tasks on the map. Also the user can import an already created route with tasks or import clear route, or even add more tasks. To summarize the user (teacher) is creating a game for students. The game consists of tasks, routes. The main goal is to create a route with points which will have a task. Is my flow correct? Do you know any similar products that can inspire me? How would you handle it?

Tasks for example (multiple choice, text etc.)
Flow attached, my questions:

What is the best way to handle adding a route to the task? Maybe creating a tab with tasks and routes? Or maybe do not add tasks to this view and focus only on the marker pins on the map and adding tasks from select to them?
The adding route with tasks should be here? Or is it enough that in the previous step you have the ability to choose a route with tasks? If yes, I want to move the imported route with task to the top and task to the bottom? The user will not be able to continue till he does not assign every task to the route?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your analogy of using a map UI works quite well, and you can find many design patterns specifically for map interfaces. Of course, whatever you decide to implement depends on specific details about the users and the use cases, such as how many starting and finishing points you can have, how many tasks you can create and how many routes you can define.

I believe that on Google Maps this is referred to as [creating a route with multiple stops](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144339?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), and other GIS or map platforms like Open Street Map will also have similar features.